# How to apply Windows taskbar changes without restarting Explorer in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, registry

This is my current code, it works but it restarts the Explorer process and that's kinda weird.

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace MyApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            ShowSmallTaskbarIcons();
            // ShowLargeTaskbarIcons();
            Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void ShowSmallTaskbarIcons()
        {
            Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced", "TaskbarSmallIcons", "1", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            RefreshExplorer();
        }

        static void ShowLargeTaskbarIcons()
        {
            var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced", writable: true);
            key.DeleteValue("TaskbarSmallIcons", throwOnMissingValue: false);
            key.Close();
            RefreshExplorer();
        }

        static void RefreshExplorer()
        {
            Process.Start("taskkill.exe", "/f /im explorer.exe");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Process.Start("explorer.exe");
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to do the same as with the "Use small taskbar buttons" toggle switch from Settings.

[image]

How to do the same with C#?

Comment: Can I ask why restarting windows explorer is unwanted?

Comment: It's a little disturbing to have stuff suddenly disappear off the screen.

Comment: `it restarts the Explorer process and that's kinda weird` you never described what `kinda weird` is in your post. You do know you are killing the task yourself and then restarting it right, please explain otherwise of what your code is doing then.

Comment: I would like to mimic what Windows does, it seems there is a way to restart or apply the taskbar changes.

Comment: Find the functions that render the taskbar and use only those. Changing variables as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to change Windows 10 taskbar icon size programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42861156/4123703)

This post has an example about how to send WM_SETTINGCHANGE message in c++.

However, there is no easy way to do it in c# wrapped function. You have to do it through p/invoke

Following post will help you do it in c#

[convert C++ code to C#: SendMessageTimeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736921/convert-c-code-to-c-sendmessagetimeout)

Comment: Do you have a list of all lParam strings I can use with SendMessageTimeout?

Comment: Should I use SendNotifyMessage() or SendMessageTimeout()?

Comment: Check msdn for lParam table. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-settingchange?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Also msdn states SendMessageTimeout is the proper function.

Comment: Regarding "lParam" values, is there a list containing all available elements like "TraySettings"?

Comment: I'd like to do the same but for the Notification Area.

Comment: Look at the part of SystemParametersInfo in the msdn link above. There is a list in link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: I can't find anything about TraySettings. :(

Comment: Oops.. it seems like a magic word. However you may check github of the adaptive taskbar. https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/68nwpq/i_just_published_adaptive_taskbar_for_windows_a/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share This auther shall be the same author of the question link I post. Never really dig into it, you have to study for that.